# GeoTools Routable Shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, geotools

Hello dear Geo Tools developers. I have discover Geo Tools few weeks ago and find it very interesting. However as I am completely new there I have a question. I try to use roads.shp file to calculate a route between two points founded here: [OpenStreetMap Shapefiles](http://www.geofabrik.de/data/shapefiles.html)
(Section **Routable Shapefiles**). It works fine. But to apply to any other region I need to have Routable Shapefile. There is a free way to found shape file for concrete place, but they are not Routable. So my question is: how to make a Routable Shapefile from general one or where to get ready Routable Shapefiles?